# What is a benzene ring minus a hydrogen atom called?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I thought it was Phenyl but the teacher said it wasnt and that it started with "A" I cant seem to figure it out

Comment: It is phenyl all right. Then again, there is a broader term: [aryl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryl).

Comment: What is the difference between aryl and arylene? She said it was close to arylene but that arylene was a more general name

Comment: Is it that the latter had a hydrogen atom removed from two benzene rings? If so, is there any other case where a benzene ring or more have one h atom removed for each(i could only find the other name for arylene that is arenediyl)

Comment: It had to be where the hydrogen atom is removed not substituted

Answer (score 3):

You could be referring to "aryl".  "Phenyl" is specific to $\ce{C_6H_5}$, "aryl" is generic to monovalent benzenoid  aromatic ring groups.